# How to extract a block diagonal element of an UpperTriangular directly to UpperTriangular type?

Tags: julia

I have an upper triangular matrix:

```
julia> UpperTriangular( [1 2 3; 0 4 5; 0 0 6] )
3×3 UpperTriangular{Int64, Matrix{Int64}}:
 1  2  3
 ⋅  4  5
 ⋅  ⋅  6
```

I want to extract a block diagonal element and save it off as another `UpperTriangular`.  I can do it like this:

```
julia> ans[2:3,2:3]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  5
 0  6

julia> UpperTriangular(ans)
2×2 UpperTriangular{Int64, Matrix{Int64}}:
 4  5
 ⋅  6
```

But that just dumps elements into a regular `Matrix` type then converts it to an `UpperTriangular`.  Is there a way to directly get an `UpperTriangular` subset from a larger `UpperTriangular` matrix?

I want to do this to avoid the intermediate step and type conversions.  Or is the compiler good enough that it doesn't matter?  Timing vs doing the same operation for a `Matrix` type produces the same result:

```
julia> @time( UpperTriangular(UpperTriangular( [1 2 3; 0 4 5; 0 0 6] )[2:3,2:3] ) )
  0.000011 seconds (3 allocations: 304 bytes)
2×2 UpperTriangular{Int64, Matrix{Int64}}:
 4  5
 ⋅  6

julia> @time( [1 2 3; 0 4 5; 0 0 6][2:3,2:3] )
  0.000004 seconds (3 allocations: 304 bytes)
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  5
 0  6
```

Does this mean that the intermediate steps are eliminated?

Comment: Do you want something that copies the block's data or just creates a view of the existing matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If you do this a lot you could make a helper function:

```
julia> triblock(A::UpperTriangular, i::UnitRange) = UpperTriangular(parent(A)[i, i]);

julia> let mat = UpperTriangular(rand(1000,1000))
         a = @btime triblock($mat, 33:77)
         b = @btime UpperTriangular($mat[33:77, 33:77])
         a == b
       end
  2.019 μs (1 allocation: 16.00 KiB)
  3.578 μs (1 allocation: 16.00 KiB)
true
```

The timing difference here because copying a block of the underlying `Matrix` (including the ignored values in the lower triangle) simpler than copying the from the wrapper -- `mat[33:77, 33:77]` is zero below the diagonal, so the loop has to do two different things (or perhaps just isn't as optimised).

You could also use `UpperTriangular(view(parent(A), i, i))` instead, which will avoid copying any data. This function will be approximately free (3ns) but check whether whatever comes next is happy to deal with an `UpperTriangular{Float64, SubArray{...` (and of course that you don't need to mutate one or the other independently).